# HTML input field number 0-100 validation with javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a question about an input field which should only accept numbers with two digits after the dot. For this scenario I created a fully functional Fiddle example - where you can see where I am stuck right now.

**My issue:** I can't change the value when it's completely selected/marked.

[Fiddle Example of my issue](https://jsfiddle.net/XuMsAwY/bnq83pra/)

The scripts check for:

- only positive numbers
- only numbers between 0 - 100
- only two digits after .
- only one . (dot) possible
- copy&paste check implementation

```
    // Check if keypressed and only number & .
    $('#inpPercent').keypress(function(event) {
      var inpVal = $(this).val();
      if ((inpVal.indexOf('.') != -1) && (inpVal.substring(inpVal.indexOf('.')).length > 2)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }

      if (isNumberRegChecked(event, this) == false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
      return isNumber(event, this)
    });

    // CHANGE VALID FEEDBACK OF INPUT FIELD
    $('#inpPercent').on('input', function(e) {
      var inpVal = $(this).val();

      if (inpVal > 100 || inpVal < 0 || !inpVal) {
        $("#inpPercent").removeClass("is-valid");
        $("#inpPercent").addClass("is-invalid");
        return false;
      } else {
        $("#inpPercent").removeClass("is-invalid");
        $("#inpPercent").addClass("is-valid");
        return true;
      }
    });


    // PREVENT COPY PASTE
    $('#inpPercent').bind("paste", function(e) {
      var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');

      if ($.isNumeric(text)) {
        if (text > 100 || text < 0) {
          $("#inpPercent").addClass("is-invalid");
        } else {
          $("#inpPercent").addClass("is-valid");
        }
        if ((text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 3) && (text.indexOf('.') > -1)) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).val(text.substring(0, text.indexOf('.') + 3));
        }
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });

    function isNumberRegChecked(evt, element) {
      var inpVal = $(element).val();
      var checkValue = /^(\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,2})?)$/.test(inpVal);
      if (checkValue == false) return false;
      return true;
    };

    // THE SCRIPT THAT CHECKS IF THE KEY PRESSED IS A NUMERIC OR DECIMAL VALUE.
    function isNumber(evt, element) {
      var charCode = evt.which ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
      if (
        (charCode != 46 ||
          $(element)
          .val()
          .indexOf('.') != -1) && // “.” CHECK DOT, AND ONLY ONE.
        (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)
      )
        return false;
      return true;
    };
```

Comment: Would you consider using <input type="number">?

Comment: A couple of issues I can see  in the `input` handler you need `var inpVal = parseFloat($(this).val());` and in the `keypress` handler your first test is failing (and is redundant anyway since `isNumberRegChecked` checks the same thing)

Comment: @ecg8 if I change it to this - then there are some ugly up&down buttons on the right  which I can't make disappear. Also after that I can enter comma and dot characters which I only want dot characters, even worse - with type="number" you can enter unlimited ...... and ,,,,,,,,

Comment: Hi you check for number .But you should validated  to add for . (dot)

Comment: @Nick yes I see - I think I tried this and run into some strange behaviour - because once I parseFloat the variable the behaviour changes unexpectetly - then unlimited characters can be entered ... please check also my Fiddle example